# moving data between two list boxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have two ListBox controls (or 2 html select controls with
runat=server) on a web page and some buttons to move data from one
listbox to another (using javascript). The problem is that when the
page gets on the server I can't get the items that I've moved from the
1st list to the second on the client, I always see the controls as
they were when the page was generated on the 1st request.

How I can see on the servers the items that I've put on the 2nd list?please provide the code in mvc3

Answer (score 0):

It seems..everytime postback .. two select boxes are refresh. Please try to put

In Page Load event

```
If(!IsPostBack)
{
   // populate data into select boxes here
}
```